# Change the text size of a TextView and a Column in TableLayout in Android

Tags: java, android, layout, text

[This is the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwNGV.png)

As you can see, I'm trying to stretch the text box so it will be next to the "NOPE" button. I'm being restricted by the column's size, and the text box's size, which I don't know how to change.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/editBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:onClick="editEvent"
        android:text="EDIT" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/attendingEventInListviewRow"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="38"
        android:height="30sp"
        android:tag="Events2goName"
        android:text="Events2go"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_arrive"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_column="37"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"
        android:onClick="selectCancelArrive"
        android:text="Nope" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Your `TextView` size is fixed to 200dp, maybe change it into 0dp and add `android:weight="1"` there?

Comment: By doing what I said, the `TextView` will occupy all of remaining space in the `TableRow`

Comment: I have tried to change the size to 250dp (without adding the weight) and it just pushed the "NOPE" button out. Than Iv'e tried what you said, and that's the result: http://prntscr.com/bxnmgm

Comment: That button has layout_weight and also width, try removing the weight, and why did you put layout_column as 37?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set width with hard code using `dp` it will not work properly with multiple screen. I don't know which screen size you testing you app .. you can set `TextView` `android:layout_width="100dp"` it will work for you I hope..

### But best is

You can set `android:weightSum` in `TableRow` and set `android:layout_weight` Views under `TableRow` ... below code is done for you. And it will fit with all screen size..

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:weightSum="10">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/editBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:onClick="editEvent"
        android:text="EDIT" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/attendingEventInListviewRow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="38"
        android:height="30sp"
        android:tag="Events2goName"
        android:text="Events2go"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_arrive"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_column="37"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"
        android:onClick="selectCancelArrive"
        android:text="Nope" />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/attendingEventInListviewRow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=""
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="38"
            android:height="30sp"
            android:tag="Events2goName"
            android:text="Events2go"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you have 3 columns (100% weight) and you want the first column use a 40% of the total weight, put `android:layout_weight="0.4"`,if the second column use a 50% put `android:layout_weight="0.5"` and the 3rd and last column uses 10% default `android:layout_weight="0.1"`